# How can I change the axis and legend font of the graph in Grafana?

Tags: graph, grafana, font-size, grafana-templating

I created a dashboard in Grafana and I have a graph. The axis and legend text font of this graph are too small to read. How can I change the font size in this graph? **Grafana version: 8.1.0.**